# DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern exceptions (java 8.0)

Tags: java, date

I don't understand the logic of this method,

Here is what I wrote :

```
LocalDate facture = LocalDate.parse("15/03/2010", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("DD/MM/YYYY"));

    System.out.println(facture);
```

Here is what I get :

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '15/03/2010' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {MonthOfYear=3, DayOfYear=15, WeekBasedYear[WeekFields[MONDAY,4]]=2010},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:1920)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1855)
    at java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:400)
    at tabeauDeBord.main(tabeauDeBord.java:21)
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {MonthOfYear=3, DayOfYear=15, WeekBasedYear[WeekFields[MONDAY,4]]=2010},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.LocalDate.from(LocalDate.java:368)
    at java.time.format.Parsed.query(Parsed.java:226)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    ... 2 more
```

What did I miss?

Best regards,

Comment: i am not totally sure but maybe it helps to change pattern to `"dd/MM/yyyy"`

Comment: Case is important in the pattern. You should use `dd/MM/yyyy`, not `DD/MM/YYYY`. See the [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

Comment: Thanks all ! it works

Answer (score 3):

You have to use lowercase d for day and lower case y for year:

```
LocalDate facture = LocalDate.parse("15/03/2010", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

For more information see the javadoc of [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

The main information you can see here:

```
   y       year-of-era                 year              2004; 04
   D       day-of-year                 number            189
   d       day-of-month                number            10
   Y       week-based-year             year              1996; 96
```